# How to stop infinite loop in subtle-slidershow.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, slider, infinite-loop

how can I stop the infinite loop of the following Ken-Burns-Slider-script? I have 3 pictures and I would like to stop the slider after animation of the third picture. Try with stop() of slideRefresh did not work (or my coding was bad).
The full code of the script can be seen on [GitHub](https://github.com/stijnvc/subtle-slideshow.js/blob/master/jquery.subtle-slideshow.js). Thanks for your help.

```
    (function($){
$.fn.slideshow = function(options){
  var slides = $(this);
  var settings = $.extend({
    randomize: true,
    slideDuration: 6000,
    fadeDuration: 1000,
    animate: true,
    slideElementClass: 'slide', 
    slideshowId: 'slideshow' 
  }, options);
  }
  $('<div id="' + settings.slideshowId + '"></div>').insertBefore(slides);
  var slideshow = $('#' + settings.slideshowId);
  var slideTimeDelta = 0;
  var resumeStartTime = 0;
  var resumeTimer;
  if(settings.animate == true){
    var cssAnimationDuration = settings.slideDuration + settings.fadeDuration;
  }else{
    slides.find('.' + settings.slideElementClass + ' span.animate').removeClass('animate');
    var cssAnimationDuration = 0;
  }
  console.log('Slideshow initialized.');
  slides.find('.' + settings.slideElementClass + ':first span.animate').addClass('active').css('animation-duration', cssAnimationDuration + 'ms')
  slides.find('.' + settings.slideElementClass + ':first').prependTo(slideshow);
  var currentSlideStartTime = Date.now();
  // Start interval loop
  slidesInterval = setInterval(slideRefresh, settings.slideDuration);
  console.log('Slideshow started.');
  if(settings.pauseOnTabBlur == true){
    $(window).focus(function() {
      console.log('Window gained focus.');
      if (paused == true) {
        console.log('Resuming slideshow.');
        resumeStartTime = Date.now();
        paused = false;
        $('#' + settings.slideshowId + ' span.active:last').removeClass('paused');
        resumeTimer = setTimeout(function(){
          slideTimeDelta = 0;
          slideRefresh();
          slidesInterval = setInterval(slideRefresh, settings.slideDuration);
        }, settings.slideDuration - slideTimeDelta);
      }
    }).blur(function() {
      paused = true;
      console.log('Window lost focus, slideshow paused.');
      if(slideTimeDelta != 0){
        var timeSinceLastPause = Date.now() - resumeStartTime;
        slideTimeDelta = slideTimeDelta + timeSinceLastPause;
        console.log('Time since last pause within this slide: ' + timeSinceLastPause + ' ms');
      }else{
        slideTimeDelta = Date.now() - currentSlideStartTime;
      }
      console.log('Current slide at ' + slideTimeDelta + ' ms.');
      $('#' + settings.slideshowId + ' span.active:first').addClass('paused');
      clearInterval(slidesInterval);
      clearTimeout(resumeTimer);
    });
  }
  function slideRefresh() {
    console.log('Slide refresh triggered.');
    currentSlideStartTime = Date.now();
    var slideshowDOM = slideshow[0];
    if(slideshowDOM.children.length == 0) {
      console.log('There are no slides in the slideshow.');
      slides.find('.' + settings.slideElementClass + ':first').prependTo(slideshow);
    }else{
      slides.find('.' + settings.slideElementClass + ':first').prependTo(slideshow);
      var slideElement = '#' + settings.slideshowId + ' .' + settings.slideElementClass;
      $(slideElement + ':first span.animate').addClass('active').css('animation-duration', cssAnimationDuration + 'ms');
      $(slideElement + ':last').fadeOut(settings.fadeDuration, function(){
        $(slideElement + ':last span.animate').removeClass('active').css('animation-duration', '0ms');
        $(slideElement + ':last').appendTo(slides);
        slides.find('.' + settings.slideElementClass).show(0);
      });
    }
  }
};
}( jQuery ));
```